# When flutter web runs, it opens window without content

Tags: flutter, web, dart, build

When I run `flutter run -d chrome`, it opens a blank window.

flutter doctor:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel master, 1.19.0-2.0.pre.73, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.1217], locale ru-RU)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions.
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.2)
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[√] VS Code (version 1.45.1)
[√] Connected device (2 available)
```

Dart version:

[image: screenshot_android_studio]

What I should do?

Comment: do you see anything suspicious if you run `flutter run -v -d chrome` ?

Comment: Rigth click on page(Chrome), then inspect -> Console. See if there is an error

Comment: I faced with this problem and the reason was my widgets structure then I tried an container with some height, width and color then it worked. After that I check size of my widgets specially MediaQuery related ones.

Comment: Can you put your code here?

Comment: @pskink no, I don't.

Comment: @CrazyLazyCat nothing.

Comment: @Lunedor I have no layout, only back.

Comment: @ArnoldParge https://github.com/DbilPL/eshop